# Flask module issue: imports a non-used Flask module

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, flask-uploads

I'm starting a Flask app and I can't run it since it keeps asking for a module not present in the app.py file :

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session, url_for
from flask_dropzone import Dropzone
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES, patch_request_class
```

Yet when I run the app, I get the same traceback error :

```
from werkzeug import secure_filename, FileStorage
ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_filename' from 'werkzeug' (D:\<username>\PythonProjects\envs\plantnet_simplon\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py)
```

**Context:** I previously launched the app with the secure_filename function, but I completley removed it afterwards. It seems the Flask server keeps an old snapshot in memory. Can someone please tell me how to start the app?

**EDIT:** Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62039637/12315247)

Comment: Have you tried installing `werkzeug`, it is a standalone library?

Comment: `werkzeug` is already installed alongside the main Flask packages.

Answer (score 1):

from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the issue and it's because `pip flask-uploads` installed for some weird reason an defectuous version of its package.

In `flask-upload.py` it should be

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
```

Not sure why pip doesn't update tot he latest version, since it's the requirements in the file on `master`.

Comment: When you do a `pip install flask-uploads` you get the latest version on PyPI, not from GitHub - releasing a new version to PyPI is a deliberate step of the maintainer, and the maintainer of Flask-Uploads prefers not to do this any more. You can use `Flask-Reuploaded` as a drop-in replacement - it is a well maintained successor.